# SQL: Improve querying latest value of n columns before given time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, monitoring

I have a huge table that contains monitoring data from industrial machines. The table has 30 so called parameter columns of which a typical query selects 2 - 7 each time. Things such as graphs & state tables are calculated from the results. Most of the calculation requires that the latest non-null value of a parameter **before given time frame** (pre-data) is also known in addition to the values **in the given time frame** (main-data).

I currently use a query for the pre-data that is executed per parameter. This is not as efficient as I'd want since it introduces **n** queries to the DB where **n** is the amount of parameters required by calculation. Is it somehow possible to acquire the pre-data with a single query (see below for examples of current queries)?

**pre-data query example (executed for fuel_cons, pwr_on & idle_counter also):**

```
SELECT
    alert_f335
FROM
    signal_value SIGV
    ,machine M /*Using old join since this is actually a Hibernate query*/
WHERE
    M.serialNumber = 'R451902'
    AND SIGV.machineId = M.id
    AND SIGV.time = (
        SELECT
            MAX(TMP.time)
        FROM
            signal_value TMP
        WHERE
            TMP.machineId = M.id
            AND TMP.time < 1370044800000 /*2013-06-01 00:00:00*/
            AND TMP.alert_f335 IS NOT NULL
    )
ORDER BY
    SIGV.time ASC
```

**main-data query example (this is ok):**

```
SELECT
    alert_f335
    ,fuel_cons
    ,pwr_on
    ,idle_counter
FROM
    machine M
INNER JOIN
    signal_value SIGV
    ON M.id = SIGV.machineId
WHERE
    M.serialNumber = 'R451902'
    AND SIGV.time >= 1370044800000 /*2013-06-01 00:00:00*/
    AND SIGV.time <= 1371340799000 /*2013-06-15 23:59:59*/
    AND (alert_f335 IS NOT NULL OR fuel_cons IS NOT NULL OR pwr_on IS NOT NULL OR idle_counter IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY
    SIGV.time ASC
```

machine table has 2 interesting columns: id & serialNumber.
signal_value has 2 interesting columns in addition to the parameter columns: machineId, time (millis).

Comment: Check execution plan. Look for Estimated number of rows and actual number of rows. Read this : http://bradsruminations.blogspot.in/2010/08/taking-hint.html

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where the results are coming back from. Let's take a look at what you're doing in the pre-data query. You're basically looking for that one row where alert_f335 is not null (plus some other filters). Let's call that row A. Now let's consider the next column, fuel_cons. If the correct row for that row is always row A, then it's simple, just stick them all in the select part of the query. But you've gone through all this trouble to post this question, so I'm assume they're not the same row.

So at some level, somebody needs to execute multiple queries. Either you do it from your application code by sending off different queries as you do now, or you ask SQL Server to run multiple queries. You can hide these queries as subqueries, but the end result is that SQL Server pretty much needs to run this 4 times. When you do manage to combine these, you'll see that the execution plan has loops or just flat out multiple branches, probably multiple branches. Thus, you're not gaining too much from merging them.

With that said, you can gain a tiny bit. These 4 queries will share the same filters for the most part, so you can tell SQL Server that they are the same queries so it will at least reuse its location in the table spool or index or whatever it decides to do. Now if you have good indices, it matters very very little. I would stick with whatever is easier to write.

As to actually merging them, I would use a CTE to create this temporary sub-table, and then use 4 subqueries to get them all in the same row:

```
with M as (
    select * from machine where id = 'R451902'
), TMP as (
    select * from signal_value 
    join M on M.id = signal_value.machineID
    where signal_value.time < 1370044800000
)
select 
    (select top 1 alert_f335 from TMP where alert_f335 is not null order by TMP.time DESC)
    ,(select top 1 fuel_cons from TMP where fuel_cons is not null order by TMP.time DESC)
    ,(select top 1 pwr_on  from TMP where pwr_on  is not null order by TMP.time DESC)
    ,(select top 1 idle_counter from TMP where idle_counter is not null order by TMP.time DESC)
```

Comment: Correct: there's no guarantee that all parameter's are non-null on one single row so I must look for the latest non-null.